# SQL Server Express 2008 replication/synchronisation

Tags: sql-server, replication

We are looking at developing a small, simple, Access system for a client using SQL Server Express (2005 or 2008) as database.  The only complicating factor is they have two offices and they will need to synchronise some (but not all) data between them.

What are my options with the **Express** edition for doing this?  Is there any advantage to using 2008 over 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look to managing this yourself -- using GUIDs for primary keys, and a last update time stamp, as well as tracking last sync, etc.

If there isn't too much to keep in sync, then it shouldn't be *too* hard

Comment: @Shaw i have the same problem and i did that with inset and delete by GUIDs but i am not getting how can i do with update using time stamp

Comment: @rahularyansharma That sounds like a different question, so you should ask it as such using the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link in the header (or just there)

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express (SQL Server Express) can serve as a Subscriber for all types of replication.

SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx).

Comment: So is there any other way of tackling the problem?

Comment: or maybe use another free database.

Comment: Client won't run to a full sql licence - and apart from syncing some data express is all that's needed.

Answer (score -1):

Following should be done:

**1)  Server - SQL 2008 Server - Publisher / Distributor**

one Central server - sql 2008 server - this would be the central place for data. You can created publication on sql server and specify which all tables need to be included in publication (before that you also need to finalize which replication method you need )

**2) Client - SQL 2008 Express - Subscriber**

in your case - each office can have sql express - you can use as many as you want. These express instances need to have subscription to the publication created by the central server.

( this also means  that the SQL server should be accessible to the client -  if you are not on intranet - VPN can help - vpn should be on - to create subscription and sync. If you don't have vpn - the server needs to have public IP and port open that client can subscribe to).